# Error MSB6006: "mtouch" exited with code 134. (MSB6006)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mono, visual-studio-mac

In my Visual Studio For Mac, I can run the project in simulator, but while archiving the app for publishing i am getting the error

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(3,3): Error MSB6006: "mtouch" exited with code 134. (MSB6006) (TestApp.iOS)

Does any one have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally got a solution the problem

> Project->AppName.iOS Options -> iOS Build (Under Build Dropdown) -> (unchecked) enable device specific builds

Hope it will help others